# How can I remove background color from crispy-forms in django

Tags: python, django, forms, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I'm using using crispy forms in my django project with bootstrap5 template pack. And want to change the graphical button behavior and remove abckground color.

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

I want to create a submit button. This is automatic adding btn-primary class.
Can I somehow disable this behavior as my current buttons should not have any background color ? In the second button I removed the background color by removing btn-primary class. But overwriting with css_class does not help. btn and btn-primary is added automatically.

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) self.helper = FormHelper() self.helper.form_method = "POST" self.helper.add_input(Submit("submit", "Abschicken", css_class="btn btn-outline-theme btn-lg d-block w-100 fw-500 mb-3"))`

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution.

I added

```
<style>
.clear_btn_background {
    --bs-btn-bg: unset;
}
</style>
```

to my html template.

and than I added this class to my Submit

```
self.helper.add_input(Submit("submit", "Abschicken", css_class="btn btn-outline-theme btn-lg d-block w-100 fw-500 mb-3 clear_btn_background", template="uni-form"))
```

if there would be an more native version this would be awesome. Otherwise this also works.